# Getting nan as loss value

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I have implemented focal loss in Pytorch with using of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02002.pdf). And ran into a problem with loss - got nan as loss function value.

This is implementation of focal loss:

```
def focal_loss(y_real, y_pred, gamma = 2):
    y_pred = torch.sigmoid(y_pred)
    return -torch.sum((1 - y_pred)**gamma * y_real * torch.log(y_pred) +
                       y_pred**gamma * (1 - y_real) * torch.log(1 - y_pred))
```

Train loop and my SegNet are working, I think so, because I have tested them with dice and bce losses.

I think errors occurs in backprop. Why can it be? Maybe my implementation is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version is working:

```
def focal_loss(y_real, y_pred, eps = 1e-8, gamma = 0):
    probabilities = torch.clamp(torch.sigmoid(y_pred), min=eps, max=1-eps)
    return torch.mean((1 - probabilities)**gamma * 
           (y_pred - y_real * y_pred + torch.log(1 + torch.exp(-y_pred))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to trying to calculate log(0).

I would recommend changing the code like this:

```
EPS = 1e-9
def focal_loss(y_real, y_pred, gamma = 2):
    y_pred = torch.sigmoid(y_pred)
    y_pred = torch.clamp(y_pred, EPS, 1. - EPS)
    return -torch.sum((1 - y_pred)**gamma * y_real * torch.log(y_pred) +
                       y_pred**gamma * (1 - y_real) * torch.log(1 - y_pred))
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried this addition, but i got the same error