# Getting NaN value from loss function for k-fold validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to implement MNIST using PyTorch Lightning. Here, I wanted to use `k-fold` cross-validation.

The problem is I am getting the `NaN` value from the loss function (for at least 1 fold). From below 3rd time, I was getting `NaN` values from the loss function.

```
Epoch 19: 100%|█████████████████████████████████| 110/110 [00:03<00:00, 29.24it/s, loss=0.963, v_num=287]
Testing: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 28/28 [00:00<00:00, 39.94it/s]

Epoch 19: 100%|█████████████████████████████████| 110/110 [00:04<00:00, 25.69it/s, loss=0.825, v_num=288]
Testing: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 28/28 [00:00<00:00, 41.19it/s]

Epoch 19: 100%|███████████████████████████████████| 110/110 [00:03<00:00, 30.19it/s, loss=nan, v_num=289]
Testing: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 28/28 [00:00<00:00, 42.15it/s
```

Or very big loss value (terminated before completing full epocs)

```
Epoch 0:  44%|█████████████▉                  | 48/110 [00:02<00:02, 22.87it/s, loss=2.08e+23, v_num=295]
```

The code I have used for data preparation, k-fold, and trainer is given below

```
def prepare_data():
  transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), 
                                transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])
  mnist_train = MNIST(os.getcwd(), train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
  mnist_test = MNIST(os.getcwd(), train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
  dataset = ConcatDataset([mnist_train, mnist_test])
  return dataset


k_folds=5
epochs=20

kfold=KFold(n_splits=k_folds,shuffle=True)

dataset = prepare_data()
model = LightningMNIST(lr_rate=0.01)

for fold, (train_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(kfold.split(dataset)):
  train_subsampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
  val_subsampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(val_idx)

  train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, num_workers=8, batch_size=512, sampler=train_subsampler)
  val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, num_workers=8, batch_size=512, sampler=val_subsampler)
  model.apply(reset_weights) # reset model for every fold
  early_stopping = EarlyStopping('train_loss', mode='min', patience=5)
  model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(dirpath=model_path+'mnist_{epoch}-{train_loss:.2f}',
                                        monitor='train_loss', mode='min', save_top_k=3)
  trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=epochs, profiler=False, callbacks = [model_checkpoint],default_root_dir=model_path) 
  trainer.fit(model, train_dataloader=train_loader)
  trainer.test(test_dataloaders=val_loader, ckpt_path=None)
```

The training step is given below

```
  def training_step(self, train_batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = train_batch
    logits = self.forward(x)
    loss = self.error_loss(logits.squeeze(-1), y.float())
    self.log('train_loss', loss)
    return {'loss': loss}
```

I assume, maybe I am doing something wrong in the k-fold data preparation or in the training step. Otherwise getting `NaN` or `very big value` is not expected for this simple problem and simple model.

I have gone through several posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050397/deep-learning-nan-loss-reasons), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325451/cost-function-turning-into-nan-after-a-certain-number-of-iterations), and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65310095/getting-nan-as-loss-value). Some of them suggested that it could happen because the dataset might contain NaN (but I think MNIST does not contain NaN as directly downloading from the module), model's learning rate is `0.01` (not too big not too small). Moreover, I believe that this post is not ***duplicated*** (because here, trying to use k-fold thought the error seems the same).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I would also try the following:
(a) set a seed and a conditional debug to stop where you get the `NaN` value, then inspect your structures starting from the loss inputs.
(b) try to run your script without K-fold, to understand if it is responsible of the error.

Comment: @aretor thanks for the suggestion. Using seed is a good idea. Would you mind checking the full code in here (https://filebin.net/m2masi1r0mhhaeh1)?

Comment: @aretor I tried several times without k-fold and the model was working fine (no error or no NaN)

Comment: I tested the code on Google Colab and the train loss does not report `NaN`, maybe it is related to your environment? Perhaps try to use one of PyTorch's `torchvision` models.

Comment: @aretor thank you for your time and I am glad that you tested the file. However, my `k-fold` implementation logic is fine (or implemented wrongly)?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, I don't see any evident error. Thus, I can only suggest you simplify your code until you find which combination is raising the error.
Check [this](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) for better reproducibility.